# Make public GitHub branches not-exploreable

Tags: git, github

For some reasons I want to create GitHub branches which must be public, but they should only be found if a user has the complete URL or the branch name.

So they should not be listet on my GitHub page nor in the Branch selection of the repository.
Examples:

- Free GitHub account with public branches, but not listet anywhere.
- Paid GitHub account where the repository is private (to be not exloreable!) but the branches are public. As I understand, the complete repository will be private and I can not make only certain branches public ?!?
- Paid GitHub account where I can create public repos/branches but configure them to not be listed. Do not know if this is possible, because I do not have a private plan, yet.
- Other options possible?

What are the options to meet this requirement with GitHub?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such information on GitHub doc. So, you cannot selectively "privatize" just a branch. GitHub has ability to make some of your branches is "protected", but this is not what you are asking actually:
https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/

I hope the following article will be useful for you: 
https://24ways.org/2013/keeping-parts-of-your-codebase-private-on-github/